# Monitoring Kafka Streams Using JMX

Tags: jmx, grafana, apache-kafka-streams, jmx-exporter

I'm running a KafkaStream application which does some transformation of the received messaged and re-insert it back to the another kafka topic. I was trying to monitor it thorugh grafana + promethus using jmx_exporter .
The problem that i'm encounering is, as soon as i have attached jmx_exporter as javaagent, I have seen two different cases

1. Sometimes the programs shutdowns, throwing some jvm exception and creates heap log.
2. Programs in running state(without any changes in the code or configuration), but no message is being consumed.

Is there something i'm missing.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue. I upgraded the JMX and it works now.

[Link to download jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/0.12.0/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar)

Comment: HI Ankur, can you share your step by step details on how did you enable kafka monitoring ?  I am following steps as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599405/kafka-and-jmx-exporter and I am unable to get it working. thanks